# Any good way to debug uncleared floats/unclosed divs on page?

Tags: html, html-parsing

These two may become an utter hell, especially when building on existing template, and upon erasing the piece of code mixed with HTML, you discover that page design is ruined. So, are there any tools to tell you, that div is unclosed and float is uncleared (and maybe some more of common HTML errors)?

Comment: See this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272327/how-to-find-the-unclosed-div-tag/15946632#15946632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is excellent and will display broken markup in the console on load. It also has excellent CSS debugging tools, such as the ability to toggle, edit live CSS(add/remove selectors and styles). It is the Swiss-Army Knife of development.

Comment: @Chestone- I couldn't notice the unclosed tag in firebug, could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Yes

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: That works for unclosed divs but it doesn't (and it shouldn't) find uncleared floats.

Comment: And is completely useless for page situated in localhost =)

Comment: Nordvind, it has an option to validate by direct input or by file upload.

Comment: My mistake then, but I guess it won't help for CMS template part anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted the FireBug and W3 Validator answers.

Another tool I find useful for tracking down unclosed DIVs is the  Checker Tool at:

http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker

which very quickly shows if and where you may have unmatched DIVs.

[image: DIV Checker Tool Example]