# How to find the unclosed div tag

Tags: html, validation

A unclosed div problem almost make me crazy. It is very difficult to track especially when the page is long and complex.

```
<div>
   <span>
       <b>Text</b>
       <a href="/">Title <span>another test</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

How can I find unclosed HTML-tags on a website?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The accepted answer below doesn't help solve the problem. I use this div checker: http://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/

Comment: try to put every closing tag in one kine then in phpstorm choose all (command+a) then (command+alt+L) to auto indent.

Comment: HTMLhint is able to do this [since October 2015](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/issues/57), just go to http://htmlhint.com/ and paste your code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As stated already, running your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is great but if your page is complex, you still may not know exactly where to find the open div.

I like using tabs to indent my code.  It keeps it visually organized so that these issues are easier to find, children, siblings, parents, etc... they'll appear more obvious.

**EDIT:**  Also, I'll use a few HTML comments to mark closing tags in the complex areas.  I keep these to a minimum for neatness.

```
<body>

    <div>
        Main Content

        <div>
            Div #1 content

            <div>
               Child of div #1

               <div>
                   Child of child of div #1
               </div><!--// close of child of child of div #1 //-->
            </div><!--// close of child of div #1 //-->
        </div><!--// close of div #1 //-->

        <div>
            Div #2 content
        </div>

        <div>
            Div #3 content
        </div>

    </div><!--// close of Main Content div //-->

</body>
```

Comment: Do you think this format is still possible when html mixed with hundreds lines of php codes?

Comment: @Don:  It's worth a try.  But you don't have to do every single line... you just have to identify the main chunks.  Then clean up the sub-chunks, etc.  Once you start cleaning up these chunks of code, the problem should reveal itself.

Comment: tabs instead of spaces?  No never.  Tabs cause numerous problems when formatting code.  I always have my editor insert spaces for tabs.

Comment: @TrevordeKoekkoek, what sorts of "numerous problems" exactly?  I'm curious only because I've never seen a problem caused by a tab used in place of four spaces.

Comment: A) This is a great question and shouldn't have been closed.  B) This top  answer isn't too great.  Yes, you should indent your code and you can put comments by the closing tag, and this looks awesome if your file is 20 lines long, but the question is more nuanced than that - these two techniques aren't enough to tell where unclosed tag is when the file is 1,000 lines long.

Comment: @AndrewKoper, a lot has changed regarding the off-topic closing reasons since 2011.  However by today's rules & reasons, if not *"too broad"*, then certainly *"primarily opinion based"*.  You can vote to re-open, flag it for a moderator to re-open, discuss this at the [Meta SO site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), and if/when re-opened post your own better answer.  Otherwise, this is not really the purpose of comments.

Comment: @AndrewKoper, also, what does the length of the file have to do with anything when it should have been written properly in the first place?  I have files that are over a thousand lines long and properly follow standard formatting.

Answer (score 46):

I made an online tool called [Unclosed Tag Finder](https://jonaquino.blogspot.com/2013/05/unclosed-tag-finder.html) which will do what you need.

Paste in your HTML, and it will give you output like "Closing tag  on line 188 does not match open tag  on line 62."

**Update:** The new location of the Unclosed Tag Finder is https://jonaquino.blogspot.com/2013/05/unclosed-tag-finder.html

Comment: Hello Jonathan, I tried it right away, but I noticed if there are any comments, your tool thinks they are tags.  E.g., `<!--  html comment here -->`.

Comment: Also, I notice if a tag is spread across lines/ broken with a carriage return (such as when it has many pieces, such as an `id`, `data`, `style`, etc. your validator doesn't calls it "broken".  Otherwise, a great tool!

Comment: This tool appears to break if there is line breaks between html attributes.

Answer (score 18):

the [World Wide Web Consortium HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is great at catching HTML errors.

Comment: It's really amazing how many cross-browser issues simply vanish when you reach "green" on the validator.

Comment: @Sparky672 I feel dirty if my code isn't green :)  Standards compliance all the way!

Comment: I noticed that the W3 Validator does not detect unclosed tags, when using html5, or it just allows using crappy code?

Comment: @jorre Unfortunately (in my opinion), HTML5 is standardized as HTML, not XHTML.  XHTML requires that almost all tags be closed, everything is lower case, etc.  Since HTML5 is purely HTML, those "pretty code" requirements are out the window, and it's now __legal__ to leave unclosed tags, have incomplete tag attributes (e.g., "<option selected value="1">"), and more.  It disappoints me, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 16):

I know that there have already been some good answers, but I came across this question with a Google Search and I wish someone would have pointed out this online  checking tool...

http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker

You just throw in a URL and it will show you the entire  map of the page. Very useful for a quick debug like I needed.

Comment: This is the most useful tool for checking div tags I've seen yet.   Its major advantage over editor "matching tags" features, is that It cuts clutter of all other code, comments, and other tags,  so you can easily focus just on the structure of the divs.  It's a simple and pretty layout.  Thanks.  Bookmarked.

Answer (score 15):

Use notepad ++ . you can find them easily

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/

Or you can **View source from FIREfox** - **Unclosed divs** will be shown in **RED**

Comment: They don't have an OSX version, btw..

Comment: The View Page Source from Firefox is really helpful: the red highlighting will still flag the problem when it's not what you though it was.

Answer (score 8):

1- Count the number of `<div` in notepad++ (Ctrl + F)
2- Count the number of `</div`

Compare the two numbers!

Comment: Classy... what about this: `<!-- </div> -->` :D

Comment: The OP already knows he has an open tag.  How does counting them identify **which** element was left open?

Comment: How do you know which div do not have closing tag out of 100??

Answer (score 2):

If you use Dreamweaver you could easily note to unclosed div. In the left pane of the code view you can see there `<>` `highlight invalid code` button, click this button and you will notice the unclosed div highlighted and then close your unclosed div. Press F5 to refresh the page to see that any other unclosed div are there.

You can also validate your page in Dreamweaver too. `File>Check Page>Browser Compatibility`, then task-pane will appear Click on `Validation`, on the left side there you'll see ► button click this to validate.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Taking Milad's suggestion a bit further, you can break your document source down and then do another find, continuing until you find the unmatched culprit.

When you are working with many modules (using a CMS), or don't have access to the W3C tool (because you are working locally), this approach is really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Div tags are easy to spot for me. Just download the file, scan it or so with netbeans, then continue debugging it. Or you can use the Google chrome developer kit, and view the page source. I'm a bit of a weird developer, I don't always use the "best" stuff. But it works for me.

I'll link you with some developer stuff I use

http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/

http://www.netbeans.org

Those are just a few of the good ones out there. I'm open to more suggestions to this list :D

Happy programming

-skycoder